# perl json output from mysql query

Tags: perl, json

I am trying to output mysql query results into JSON format,but struggling to output the array in the format i want.

my sql table is as below

```
Array1,Type,Somevalue
Record1,Type1,1
Record1,Type2,2
Record1,Type3,3
Record2,Type1,4
Record3,Type1,5
Record3,Type3,6
```

My perl code to retrive mysql rows and parse into json is below

```
use DBD::Mysql;
use JSON::XS;
use IO::File;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper::Names;
use POSIX;


my $json = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;

my $datasource = "dbi:mysql:database=$dbname;host=$host;port=$port";
#PERL DBI CONNECT
my $dbh =DBI->connect($datasource, $dbusername, $dbpasswd) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
#PREPARE THE QUERY
my $query1=qq(select * from table);

my $query_handle1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);

#EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle1->execute();

#my variable
my $i;

my @Types = ("Type1","Type2","Type3");
my @Array1 = ("Record1","Record2","Record3","Record4");
my @sql_query_1_Results;

#LOOP THROUGH RESULTS and store results for later processing
while(my $row = $query_handle1->fetchrow_hashref) {
push @sql_query_1_Results, $row;
}

# create data arrays for record we should get 3 arrays with values
for ($i=0;$i<=$#sql_query_1_Results;$i++)
{
push @{$sql_query_1_Results[$i]->{record}},$sql_query_1_Results[$i]->{Some_Value};
}

foreach my $record(@Array1){
$json = encode_json({ 'name' => $record, 'data'=> \@{$record}  });
push @chart1_data, $json;
}
#DISCONNECT FROM THE DATABASE
$dbh->disconnect();

#JSON OUTPUT
my $chart1_data_json=encode_json( { chart1 => \@chart1_data } );
print $chart1_data_json;
```

The above code will give me the array as below

```
Record1=[1,2,3]
Record2=[4]
Record3=[5,6]
```

but i would like to maintain the order of the type i.e in the format below

```
Record1=[1,2,3]
Record2=[4,0,0]
Record3=[5,0,6]
```

Comment: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Never include `DBD::*` modules directly. Instead `use DBI;`.

Comment: @dgw Tks. i normally include warning but will include strict and use DBI.Can you please advise on how to get ordered array's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use JSON::XS;
use IO::File;
use Data::Dumper::Names;
use POSIX;

my $json = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;

my ( $dbname , $host , $port , $dbusername , $dbpasswd ) ; # Satisfy strict

my $datasource = "dbi:mysql:database=$dbname;host=$host;port=$port";
#PERL DBI CONNECT
my $dbh =DBI->connect($datasource, $dbusername, $dbpasswd) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
#PREPARE THE QUERY
my $query1=qq(select * from table);

my $query_handle1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);

#EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle1->execute();

my @Types = ("Type1","Type2","Type3");
my @Array1 = ("Record1","Record2","Record3","Record4");

# BEGIN modified data munching
my %result ;
my %Type_Pos ;
@Type_Pos{@Types} = ( 0 .. $#Types ) ; # Map the type to position

while( my $row = $query_handle1->fetchrow_hashref ) {
  if( ! exists $result{$row->{Array1}} ) {
    # Initialize Record with all possible types
    $result{$row->{Array1}} = [ map { 0 } @Types ] ;
  }
  $result{$row->{Array1}}->[$Type_Pos{$row->{Type}}] = $row->{Somevalue} ;
}

my @chart1_data = map { encode_json( { 'name' => $_, 'data'=> $result{$_} } )
                      } sort keys %result ;
# END modified data munching

$dbh->disconnect();

#JSON OUTPUT
my $chart1_data_json=encode_json( { chart1 => \@chart1_data } );
print $chart1_data_json;
```

This should do what you asked.
Instead of saving the data in an array I contruct a hash where the record is the key and an arrayref of Somevalue (in order of types) is the value.

Comment: thanks for your help. There are few syntax errors in the while loop. i tired to fix as below but dont see the values in the array. Can you please have a look?
while( my $row = $query_handle1->fetchrow_hashref ) {
  if( ! exists $result{$row->{Array1} }) {
    # Initialize Record with all possible types
    $result{$row->{Array1} }= [ map { 0 } @Types ] ;
  }
  $result{$row->{Array1}->[$Type_Pos{$row->{Type}}]} = $row->{Somevalue} ;
}

Comment: @Linus You were right, always the same mistake ... corrected now.

Comment: appreciate your help. i am still unclear on the statement " if( ! exists $result{$row->{Array1}} )" is that meant to check if the row has anyone of the elements in Array1? and can you also explain  "$result{$row->{Array1}} = [ map { 0 } @Types ]"

Comment: Ok, I start with the empty hash `%result`. When I now examine a row I'll check if Array1 exists within the result hash (Record1, Record2, Record3 in your case). If this is not the case I'll add an arrayref that has as many zeros as the array `@Types` has elements. And then I'll just update the column within this arrayref that belongsto the Type of the row element.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you.can u help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135249/highcharts-correct-json-input#comment13089646_10135249 as well?

Comment: the json put with the \" is nor parsing properly in my js. any ideas on how to encode without these. example output is {"chart1":["{\"name\":\"Record 1\",\"data\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]}","{\"name\":\"Record 2\",\"data\":[\"4\",0,0]}","{\"name\":\"Record 3\",\"data\":[\"5\",0,\"6\"]}"]}

i am looking for something like beloe
{"chart1":[{"name":"Record 1","data":["1","2","3"]}",{"name":"Record 2","data":["4",0,0]}",{"name":"Record 3","data":["5",0,"6"]}"]}